# regex for base64 encoded crt file

Tags: c#, regex, certificate, x509

I'm trying to receive the base64 certificates (without the **-----BEGIN/END CERTIFICATE-----**) from x509 .crt file using regex in c#.
but without success.
I'm using chained certificate.
What I'm doing wrong?
Here is the regex that I used:

> (?:[\nA-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=)

The input:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

MIIGzDCCBLSgAwIBAgIBATANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADCBpjELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMx

DjAMBgNVBAgTBVRleGFzMRQwEgYDVQQHEwtTYW4gQW50b25pbzEaMBgGA1UEChMR

R2xvYmFsU0NBUEUsIEluYy4xFDASBgNVBAsTC0VuZ2luZWVyaW5nMRUwEwYDVQQD

EwxtaWtlLXJvb3QtY2ExKDAmBgkqhkiG9w0BCQEWGW1oYW1iaWRnZUBnbG9iYWxz

Y2FwZS5jb20wHhcNMTAxMTE4MjEyMzA4WhcNMTUxMTE3MjEyMzA4WjCBmDELMAkG

A1UEBhMCVVMxDjAMBgNVBAgTBVRleGFzMRowGAYDVQQKExFHbG9iYWxTQ0FQRSwg

SW5jLjEUMBIGA1UECxMLRW5naW5lZXJpbmcxHTAbBgNVBAMTFG1pa2UtaW50ZXJt

ZWRpYXRlLWNhMSgwJgYJKoZIhvcNAQkBFhltaGFtYmlkZ2VAZ2xvYmFsc2NhcGUu

Y29tMIICIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAg8AMIICCgKCAgEAsF+vlQfZnssDsqFx

IXCGHST1jiTHJGGHiiwc9Qb1NPDbyvcdNXvcfkdyYjd8VlYyo3/jnj6xx3PxzJhG

NmnBGJ0I7h/RFJaG7nmGfeWUHCLsVjGfQeEjC++d6zzE3unPOiLVIhv9abD6kISa

hLdltOBcT19mqg1yG4Q4XExjeYmSYGFiDIdv+WwwUssTyPdppaaWcsjNaFcmuopU

RfmcfULPFwvFN6LsgvSTYwYe9l8421fA5c+WiR1JomjGuJT/0sITpzQRCenWi0S0

WZuftT61+fU0/OxINhgO4yK6C1eOoaxmoEG2oVm2o4Bjy9ceYN2UqdRGt8t/23/h

Wog3vEwdoHqghrjeiGWWs98qfzINKokiMd7APcxdkZ1SzyvOEWht4V3/XedleiMx

8WGjbVtRg/k4Hgf2TGwxcw==

-----END CERTIFICATE-----

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

MIIG4jCCBMqgAwIBAgIJAJjguYVnU08GMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAMIGmMQswCQYD

VQQGEwJVUzEOMAwGA1UECBMFVGV4YXMxFDASBgNVBAcTC1NhbiBBbnRvbmlvMRow

GAYDVQQKExFHbG9iYWxTQ0FQRSwgSW5jLjEUMBIGA1UECxMLRW5naW5lZXJpbmcx

FTATBgNVBAMTDG1pa2Utcm9vdC1jYTEoMCYGCSqGSIb3DQEJARYZbWhhbWJpZGdl

QGdsb2JhbHNjYXBlLmNvbTAeFw0xMDExMTgyMTE5NDdaFw0xNTExMTcyMTE5NDda

MIGmMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEOMAwGA1UECBMFVGV4YXMxFDASBgNVBAcTC1NhbiBB

bnRvbmlvMRowGAYDVQQKExFHbG9iYWxTQ0FQRSwgSW5jLjEUMBIGA1UECxMLRW5n

aW5lZXJpbmcxFTATBgNVBAMTDG1pa2Utcm9vdC1jYTEoMCYGCSqGSIb3DQEJARYZ

bWhhbWJpZGdlQGdsb2JhbHNjYXBlLmNvbTCCAiIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggIP

xYK3mO1034kBdDxmVoBeEwfjWWPyC/uyFGwCNZCzoAQGMxNAnj33NBiCLHJRo1Z5

BxirSSMxOT4LEkmkOhuTyKB0TJZf+8wP8pK5BsO3xjO+uM1K3LY=

-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: I think I found an answer.  certificate file have \n inside the blob.
So I added it to the allowed characters.
(?:[\nA-Za-z0-9+\/]{4})*(?:[A-Za-z0-9+\/]{2}==|[A-Za-z0-9+\/]{3}=)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would simply write a regex that returns anything between *START* and *END*

```
var START = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----";
var END = "-----END CERTIFICATE-----";
var certs = Regex.Matches(DATA, START+ "(.+?)" + END,RegexOptions.Singleline)
                 .Cast<Match>()
                 .Select(m => Convert.FromBase64String(m.Groups[1].Value))
                 .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid of mufti-language where "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" is in other language

Comment: @Igal then try `-----.+?-----(.+?)-----.+?-----`

Comment: +1. I don't believe it would be valid .cer if "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" is in some different language...

Comment: This is my final regex:   -{5}BEGIN CERTIFICATE-{5}\s+([^-]+)-{5}END CERTIFICATE-{5}